# JavaScriptHelper not working in Facebook php-sdk

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Javascript SDK for setting cookie and accessToken and then using location.replace to call my php script.

The code of PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

echo'Login';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
   echo $accessToken;                      //Nothing is displayed
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
 echo'in';
  // Logged in
}
?>
```

The Javascript code :

```
    <script>
logInWithFacebook = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);}); //I get the output over here
      location.replace('http://localhost/fee/login-callback.php');
      } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'xxx',
      cookie: true,
      version: 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Please tell me why I'm not getting accessToken in php file.

Comment: From docs: [If a user has already authenticated your app, you can also obtain an access token.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptHelper/5.0.0) Did you have an user authenticated?

Comment: Yes, After authenticating the user I display his/her name in the console using Graph Api and then I redirect(location.replace) to the php script